# Trouble understanding regex in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

Having trouble understanding regular expressions.
How do you write regular expressions that find:

1. All occurrences of `<digit>:<digit>`
2. Fractions
3. All occurrences of only letters, digits and spaces between parenthesis
4. Dates in the form `, dddd` where `d` is a digit, and can have 0 or more spaces between the `,` and the digits
5. Two different regular expressions to find all words with `mm` in them
6. All occurrences of `mm` or `nn` followed by a lower-case vowel

Where is a good source to learn about regular expressions?

Comment: Regexes in general [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html). Specifically for vim [here](http://vimregex.com/).

Comment: the items in your list (2-6) are `&&` or `||` or they are 5 different things?please make some example, what input do you have, and what do you want to get. some of them is not good job for regex. e.g. 2)

Comment: This smells a bit like a homework assignment...

Comment: @jahroy wow! there is homework about vim nowadays? nice!

Comment: Seriously... Sounds like the best course evar!  I would have never thought there were such classes, but when I read this question it made me wonder.

Comment: @jahroy Yes, this is homework. Sorry but I really need help on regular expressions in VIM!

Comment: I'm glad somebody is teaching this... I think searching with regular expressions is one of the most powerful things you can learn to do as a programmer.  It shocks me to no end that none of my coworkers do this at all!  I could not surive without regex searches.

Answer (score 1):

See http://vimregex.com/ for some explanation, but here are a few examples for your questions:

1. all occurrences of `<digit>:<digit>`

   ```
   \d\+:\d\+
   ```
2. fractions

   ```
   \d\+\/\d\+
   ```
3. all occurrences of only letters,digits and spaces between parenthesis

   ```
   ([a-zA-Z\d ]\+)
   ```
4. dates in the form “, dddd” where d is a digit, and can have 0 or more spaces between the , and the digits

   ```
   , *\d\{4}
   ```
5. two different regular expressions to find all words with “mm” in them

   ```
   mm
   ```

   or...

   ```
   m\{2}
   ```
6. all occurrences of 'mm' or 'nn' followed by a lower-case vowel

   ```
   \(mm\|nn\)[aeiou]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For learning regex I can wholeheartedly recommend [RegexOne](http://regexone.com/)!

It'll guide you through the basics of regex, giving you the building stones before going on to adding them together so you can build those long and at first glance, somewhat cryptic, regexes.

Keep in mind that the regex style used in Vim is a little bit different, such as how groups `\(<match>\)` and default escaped characters is used. But this is all easy when you know the basics of regex, and could be said to be like bicycling. It's not difficult learning to ride a new bike once you already know riding a bicycle.

Comment: Thanks. That website is helpful. I'll work through those examples.